# Blazor webassembly - IdentityServer EventSink and HttpContext

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor webassembly application, in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with IdentityServer. 
As IdentityServer handle all login, logout, register, ... events, I'm trying to catch theses events in order to obtain some informations about users.

To be clear, I'm trying to memorize the login Date, and to catch new users registration to give them some role automatically.

Here all the services I use in my startup class :

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
            });

        // Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

I've implemented the IEventSink pattern (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/topics/events.html) :

```
public class IdentityServerEventSink : IEventSink
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public IdentityServerEventSink(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task PersistAsync(Event @event)
    {
        if (@event.Id.Equals(EventIds.ClientAuthenticationSuccess))
        {
            var identity = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
            var id = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var user = await userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the startup.cs :

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IEventSink, IdentityServerEventSink>();
```

But when I get in the ClientAuthenticationSuccess event, the identity is always anonymous.

I tried also in the middleware but I have the same issue :

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next.Invoke();
            //handle response
            //you may also need to check the request path to check whether it requests image
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
                //retrieve uer by userName
                using (var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
                {
                    var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
                    user.LastLogon = System.DateTime.Now;
                    dbContext.Update(user);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        });
```

Do you have any ideas ? 
I heard HttpContextAccessor is a bad things in Blazor.

Comment: I don't know if this exactly what you're looking for but maybe this helps: Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0. / .NET & EF 5 Preview - Multiple Roles and Additional User Claims

See: https://github.com/JeepNL/Blazor-WASM-Identity-gRPC

Comment: Thanks it's not exactly what I needed but it's well interesting !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after an update the middleware delegate works !

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
        using (var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.LastLogon = System.DateTime.Now;
                user.LastIpAddress = context.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();

                dbContext.Update(user);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Just be carefull to the order of app.use... in the Configure method ! You need to add this **AFTER** `app.UseIdentityServer(); app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();`

But badly the EventSink from IdentityServer still doesn't work, the `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity` is always anonymous.

Comment: How are you handling the registration of new users?  I've been researching for the best way to handle this in Blazor Web Assembly, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on that part. Documentation seems to only cover Authentication and Authorization, and not the actual registration of new users. It sounds as if you're registering users from within Identity Server, but I'm curious as exactly how you are handling that from within the blazor client. Do you have any sample code or documentation that I can view?

Comment: That's a good question ! I haven't take care of the registration yet, but I'll need to control it.
Maybe you can have a look to the blazor-workshop repo on github. They use IdentityServer.
If you have any answear to your question, I would like to here it